# quitar checked a input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, javascript-objeto

Comunidad necesito colaboración,

Tengo un grupo de checkbox con una misma clase "ck" al cargar la pagina algunos de los checkbox van a marcarse cuando el valor sea 1 y van a quedar con las propiedades (disabled y readonly). Tengo un checbox con la clase "checkTodos" esta me permite seleccionar y des seleccionar todos los checkbox.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que necesito es que al momento de des seleccionar el checkbox "checkTodos" no me quite el checked de los checkbox que el valor es 1 y por contrario me quite el checked de los demas.

Con el siguiente codigo  selecciono todos los checkbox y los des selecciono

```
$(".checkTodos").click(function(event)
        {
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(".ck:checkbox:not(:checked)").prop("checked", true);
            }else{
                $(".ck:checkbox:checked").prop("checked", false);
            }
        }
    );
```

el input es el siguiente:

```
<input class="single_select ck " type="checkbox" style="position: static; cursor: pointer;" />
```

y para marcar el checked utilizo lo siguiente

```
<? if($p ->valorCheck == 1){
      echo 'checked readonly disabled';
 }else{ ?>
```

Espero me puedan colaborar, de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Solo necesitas especificar que no afecte a los que estén deshabilitados agregando `:not(:disabled)` al selector CSS:

```js
$(".checkTodos").click(function(event) {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".ck:not(:checked):not(:disabled)").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(".ck:checked:not(:disabled)").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkTodos"> Todos</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ck"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ck"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ck"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ck"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="ck" disabled readonly checked><br>
```